# Navigation history in Silverlight navigation application

Tags: silverlight, navigation

I would like to be able to get the navigation history from my users of a navigation application. 
I have a frame and can use canGoBack(), and goBack method. But I would like to be able to see from what page they are navigation from when they enter a new page. How can I extract the history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NavigationService.CurrentSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.currentsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Property will tell you your current location.

You could call this before the call to `GoBack` to store the uri and then query that value once the navigation has completed.

There is also the [Page.OnNavigatedFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Method which takes a [NavigationEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Class as it's argument. This might give you the information you need.

Comment: This answer is also good for the specific case you ask for - my answer is about the more general question about getting to the history in its entirety.

Comment: Thank alot for the help, I resolved it by storing a list with uri's and then querying it when needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the history, you'd have to store it yourself by listening to each instance of Frame.Navigated (or NavigationService.Navigated) and keeping it somewhere.